# Tmux installation problems

Tags: linux, installation, tmux

hI,
I am trying to install the terminal multiplexer tmux on my Debian Lenny server so that I can have multiple terminals through ssh.

However I have had a lot of difficulty installing it from the debian package, and by compiling it. When I try the package it says something about the wrong version of libc6, and when I compile it I get the following error:

```
server.o: In function `server_start':
server.c:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `event_reinit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tmux] Error 1
```

Help would be very much appreciated,
RayQuang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your packages may be a little different, but on Ubuntu I had to:

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-1.4-2 libevent-dev libncurses5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

See also:
https://superuser.com/questions/219095/tmux-compilation-error-in-andlinux-ubuntu

Quoting the answer from there:

> I just found out that libevent-dev that comes in ubuntu repository wasn't new enough. It worked fine after I installed the latest version of libevent from source. Remember to remove the libevent-dev if you've already installed it via apt-get.